# NSComboBox with bindings to NSTreeController

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller, nscombobox

I have a NSTreeController/NSOutlineView with children and a NSComboBox. I would like to only show the top level objects in the combobox and not the children. Can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, it's just been confirmed that I'm stupid.

Just added a NSArrayController and used bindings with that one instead.